# Template argument deduction for initializer_list with forwarding

Tags: c++, initializer-list, perfect-forwarding

I want to use perf. forwarding with initializer_list (curly braces), but I've failed in writing code that could be compiled.

How to make type deduction working in the following sample of code?

```
#include <utility>

template <class _T> struct B {
    _T a;
    _T b; };

template <class _T> void bar(B<_T>&& a) {}

template <class _T> void bar(B<_T>& a) {}

template <class _T> struct A {
    template <class __T>
    void foo(__T&& a) {
        bar(std::forward<__T>(a));
    } };

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.foo({1, 3}); }
```

I know that it's possible to do perfect forwarding with variadic template argument, like this:

```
#include <utility>

template <class _T>
struct B {
    _T a;
    _T b;
};

template <class _T>
void bar(_T&& v1, _T&& v2) {
    B<_T> b{v1, v2};
}

template <class _T>
void bar(_T& v1, _T& v2) {
    B<_T> b{v1, v2};
}

template <class _T>
struct A {
    template <class... Args>
    void foo(Args&&... args) {
        bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.foo(1, 3);
}
```

But I want to call `foo` with cutee curly braces.

Comment: Care with naming: names containing `__` are reserved. See [keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

Comment: I guess you can't do it. The compiler will not be able to deduce `{1, 3}` to be an `initializer_list`.

Comment: ... as are names like `_T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{1, 3}` has no type, so cannot be deduced for "generic" template type.

You might use overload with `std::initializer_list` to handle it;

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    template <class U>
    void foo(U&& a) {
        bar(std::forward<U>(a));
    }

    template <class U>
    void foo(std::initializer_list<U> a) {
        bar(a); // assuming bar(std::initializer_list<U>)
    }

};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.foo({1, 3});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Along with other serious shortcomings, `std::initializer_list` cannot be deduced by simply using the `{...}` syntax.

```
a.foo(std::initializer_list{1, 3})
```

Will pass deduction properly, but you won't be able to invoke `bar` with it as you expect an instance of `B`.

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1EIbXq)

---

How about just

```
a.foo(B<int>{1, 3})
```

?